# How to get attribute php html simple parset?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I apologize in advance but my English is not the strongest.
I have this code:

```
<div id="divColourImages">
    <ul id="ulColourImages" class="colourImages">`

        <li id="cvli12003003" title="Click to select Black/Charcoal" colvar-id="12003003" data-text="Black/Charcoal" class="tooltip colorImgli variantHighlight">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/12003003_bs.jpg" alt="colour">
            </a>
        </li>

        <li id="cvli12003004" title="Click to select Chalk/Black" colvar-id="12003004" data-text="Chalk/Black" class="tooltip colorImgli">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="pic0.jpg" alt="colour">
            </a>
        </li>

        <li id="cvli12003022" title="Click to select Navy/White" colvar-id="12003022" data-text="Navy/White" class="tooltip colorImgli">`
            <a href="#">
                <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="colour">
            </a>
        </li> 
        <li id="cvli12003037" title="Click to select White/Navy" colvar-id="12003037" data-text="White/Navy" class="tooltip colorImgli">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="pic2" alt="colour">
            </a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

My question is how to get(parse) all information on atributes data-text and colvor-id  on `<li>` and convert.
Please help me! My idea is data-text information change on select option menu and colvar-id for value
Sample this:

```
<select>
   <option value="12003004">Chalk/Black</option>
   <option value="12003022">Navy/White</option>
   <option value="12003037">White/Navy</option>
</select>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty select with `id="sel"` to your html

```
<select id="sel"></select>
```

and then with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function(){
         // debug
         console.log($(this).attr('colvar-id'));
         console.log($(this).attr('data-text'));
         console.log($(this).attr('title'));
         // go for the select
         $('#sel').append(
             $('<option></option>')
                .val($(this).attr('colvar-id'))
                .html($(this).attr('data-text')));   
              });
         });

});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/KP75g/)

**Update**

Instead of using the `$(li)` selector, you could also use `$('[id^="cvli"]')`.

(All elements, whose id are starting with "cvli".)